# Keeping Template from escaping & to &amp

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django Templates, I want to pass in a string as follows:

```
trademard = "MyCompany &trade;"
```

and it will show up as the correct HTML entity of TM

However, when it is passed in, ™ is turned into &trade;

How can I get my desired results w/o surrounding the html block w/ {% verbatim %}

Thanks

Comment: `{{trademard|safe}}` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
mystring = mark_safe("MyCompany &trade;")
```

works great!

Answer (score 8):

An alternative method, as @karthikr said is to use the `|safe` filter at the template level:

`{{ trademard|safe }}`

Obviously, be careful in using either of these methods -- if the data comes from a user-entered source you could cause the introduction of HTML errors or even security vulnerabilities to your application.

The official documentation has a [detailed explanation of HTML escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping) that all Django developers should spend time understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I had to search in many places to find out a solution that does not depend on the `safe` tag. Maybe this can help someone:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{trademard}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

This disables the automatic html escaping. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/) the result is the same as applying the safe tag, but can be more useful when dealing with a bigger chunk of data.